# Optimize `git status` for shell prompt

Tags: git, shell, command-prompt

Recently I wrote my own shell prompt like this:

```bash
git_status() {
  if git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    local untracked=0
    local modified=0
    local modified_updated=0
    local new_added=0
    local deleted=0
    local deleted_updated=0
    local renamed_updated=0

    local status_items=$(git status --porcelain)
    if [ -n "$status_items" ]; then
      while IFS= read -r item; do
        case "${item:0:2}" in
          "??") ((untracked++));;
          "MM") ((modified++)); ((modified_updated++));;
          " M") ((modified++));;
          "M ") ((modified_updated++));;
          "A ") ((new_added++));;
          " D") ((deleted++));;
          "D ") ((deleted_updated++));;
          "R ") ((renamed_updated++));;
        esac
      done <<< "$status_items"

      local result=""
      local index=""
      local workdir=""

      if [ "$untracked" -ne 0 ]; then
        workdir+="${untracked}?"
      fi
      if [ "$modified" -ne 0 ]; then
        workdir+="${modified}*"
      fi
      if [ "$modified_updated" -ne 0 ]; then
        index+="${modified_updated}*"
      fi
      if [ "$new_added" -ne 0 ]; then
        index+="${new_added}+"
      fi
      if [ "$deleted" -ne 0 ]; then
        workdir+="${deleted}x"
      fi
      if [ "$deleted_updated" -ne 0 ]; then
        index+="${deleted_updated}x"
      fi
      if [ "$renamed_updated" -ne 0 ]; then
        index+="${renamed_updated}^"
      fi

      if [ -z "$index" ]; then
        index=",,Ծ"
      fi
      if [ -z "$workdir" ]; then
        index="Ծ,,"
      fi

      result="${index}ω${workdir}"

      echo "$result"
    else
      echo ""
    fi
  else
    echo ""
  fi
}

thy_prompt() {
    result="┌─[\u@\h]─[\w]"

    if [ -n "$(git_status)" ]; then
        result+="─[$(git_status)]"
    fi

    result+="─[\t]─[$?]\n└─> λ "
    PS1="$result"
    # echo "$result"
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=thy_prompt
```

However, it came out that the command `git status --porcelain` had dragged down the perfomance of shell prompt building. I can feel the delay of the building process, which impacted my user experience.

I'd like to know if there's any way to improve the performance of `git status` or the building process, like synchronization or something else.

I've noticed that p10k's `git status` has excellent performance, and I'm wondering if there's a way to use it in the shell prompt I'm writing myself. I don't want to use a plugin, because I'm writing this to make it easier for me to use the shell in a network-less environment.

Comment: 2 random remarks (just reading your code, not actually testing anything): a. you call your `git_status` function twice, store the result in a string and check that string ; b. in my experience reading lines in bash is not very fast, have you tried writing your loop in another scripting language ? awk, perl, python ...

Comment: Thank you for your advices, I have noticed that I called the slow function twice. I will try to use `awk` to optimize my function.

Comment: note that: if running `git status --porcelain` alone is slow, your script will be at least as slow as that. If this is the pain point: look into reasons why it takes time

Comment: Finaly I added more logic that can detect when I input `cd` or `git`, then it will call the `git status`. In the other case, it only use the last result of `git status`.